# why <xsl:apply-templates/> outputs the values of all ancestors tags

Tags: xml, xslt

As far as I know the XPath expression "/" should set the node context to the child axis of the root node. Here is the xml:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<test-case name="test-case-1">
    <object-under-test category="template" name="text-align"/>
    <parameters>
        <input name="text">text</input>
        <input name="min-lenght">8</input>
        <input name="align">left</input>
        <output name="result"/>
    </parameters>
    <criteria>
        <criterion class="equal" to="'text '"/>
    </criteria>
</test-case>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <test>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </test>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What is the default match pattern for `<xsl:apply-templates>`?
Why I get as an output the values of all tags?

This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>text 8 left</test>
```

Comment: Your questions in future would be more understandable if you used the correct terminology. You're using "tags" to mean "elements", "ancestors" to mean "descendants", "XPath expression" to mean "match pattern", "node context" to mean "context node", and "child axis" to mean nothing at all: the context node is a node, not an axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as I know the XPath expression "/" should set the node context
>   to the child axis of the root node.

No, it sets the context to the `/` root node itself.

> What is the default match pattern for `<xsl:apply-templates>`?

"*In the absence of a `select` attribute, the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction processes all of the children of the current node.*"
http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Applying-Template-Rules

> Why I get as an output the values of all tags?

It's because of the [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) that are applied when your stylesheet does not have a template that matches the nodes you have applied templates to. In a nutshell, the built-in templates copy all descendant text nodes to the output.